# Temporary storage for fast access

Tags: jakarta-ee, mongodb

I am using mongodb and java / Servlet. I store a employee information in mongo as a single record. when ever employee access/modify his details i want to update in mongo. Is there a way to save entire employee record in temporary place for fast access.

I want to get a copy of one employee record and save it in temporary place and modify it when needed. Is there any way to do it?

thanks,
suresh

Comment: Having all employees in a single record seems like a rather bad solution to me. What made you go that route to begin with? I'd fix that rather than create some sort of employee cache.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb should be fast enough for your purpose, however you can always take advantage of cache by using a HashMap:

```
Map<String,Object> empInfoMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

Now you can add employee objects into the map. Whenever you need to modify an object just get the object and modify the data in it.
When you are sure that you no longer going to modify the employee object, write the data into mongodb.